# Is there a Blockchain per bitcoin wallet?

Tags: blockchain

According to this article "[A gentle introduction to bitcoin](https://bitsonblocks.net/2015/09/01/a-gentle-introduction-to-bitcoin/)", it looks like a blockchain is created per Wallet.

Is this correct or am I misunderstanding it? If my assumption is not correct, what determines when to create a Blockchain?

[image: Bitcoin Wallet]

Answer (score 1):

"The blockchain" is the universal list of all Bitcoin transactions that have ever been confirmed.

A new wallet doesn't "create" a new blockchain.  Rather, it downloads a *copy* of the existing universal blockchain.  It does create some new files on its own computer to store the data it downloaded, but the data itself isn't new.

(This assumes it is a "full node" wallet.  "Thin" or SPV wallets don't download it; they rely on other nodes to tell them what transactions already exist.)